# How do I make an object transparent but colored?

Tags: materials, transparency

So I can make a transparent object but... I can't change the color of it. Any part of the object that is in front of another object puts a colored tint on it (That doesn't really matter since the object won't be covering another object in renders anyway). But any part of the object that isn't covering another one just ends up black.

I have a transparent background in the rendered image, and I want the object to appear transparent lime green over the fully clear background, making that part half-opaque. But, while it is transparent, it isn't colored the way I want.

Here's an example of what it looks like in rendered mode in the viewport. The plane has a transparent material and the cube doesn't have any. I want plane to appear lime green over the background but instead it only does on other objects like the cube, and it just looks black on the background:
[image: Rendered]

Strangely enough it does have color everywhere in the material preview, even on the background, it's just still kinda dark though:
[image: Material Preview]

Here's an image of my node setup for the transparent object that I learned from a tutorial:
[image: oof]

If anyone can help, that would be very appreciated!

I'm using Blender 2.81 by the way.

Comment: Can you show what did you see in render/viewport? It's kind of confuse what did you do in your scene, and also Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: I'm using EEVEE. I'm trying to give you an image, it's just Blender isn't working that well for me right now, hold on.

Comment: Okay, I added some images to the post, as well as some more text.

Comment: Glass with IOR set to 1 could do the job but loss the transparency, interesting question